# HTTP Status 404 - /ssssnpm//promotional.jsp error

Tags: java, jsp, http, tomcat, connectivity

Whenever I connect to my broadband internet, it shows this message -
"HTTP Status 404 - /ssssnpm//promotional.jsp"
Apache Tomcat/7.0.57

I searched a lot about this issue but couldn't find it. Everyone is talking about Tomcat or Apache servers. I don't use any IDE. I am not a programmer, so I didn't write any codes. I am just not able to open any web page. Whenever I enter any URL, it redirects me to another URL, which seems to be an IP address. And, that page shows this error message (wrote above).

I suspect that it could be because of an antivirus I installed a couple of days ago on my laptop and my phone as well. But, it's showing the same error to my brother's phone on which this antivirus isn't installed.

other internet connections are working fine on my laptop - like my mobile internet.

Please help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now. It was some server error as it was unable to load a file something **"promotional.jsp"** 
The message Apache Tomcat/7.0.75 was a bit confusing to me. So, posted a question here.

Answer (score -1):

this is not internet connection problem this is background code problem apache could not found specific file which you want to access
thanks

Comment: Whenever I try to open any web page, this error arrives. why Apache would need a file from the background with some promotional.jsp file every time I want to open a page.